# MAC data width for 100/40 Gigabit Ethernet system on Xilinx Ultrascale core

Tags: networking

If I remember correctly, Xilinx's 10 Gigabit Ethernet Mac core has 32 bits data bus connected at the mac side at 156 Mhz....

What about the 100 Gigabit and 40 Gigabit Ethernet Subsystem in the Ultrascale+ FPGA's from Xilinx?

How wide is the data bus going into Mac core and 40GbE Mac core?  and what's clock rate on the mac side?

Also, if using backplane KR4 standard to transport 100GbE... how many GTH transceivers on the phy side?

Answer (score 0):

100GbE on an Xilinx Ultrascale has a 512-bit MAC local bus at ~322 MHz...

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer, can you answer the question?